# Can't write log file in Linux using PHP

Tags: php, linux, logging, ejabberd, chmod

I'm running CentOS 6.5 on a Google Compute Engine instance which I use for an ejabberd XMPP server. I also have php 5 installed and ejabberd is configured to use a [php script](https://www.ejabberd.im/extauth) to authenticate users.
So far so good - ejabberd executes the script and recieves the correct result from it. The problem is: I want the PHP script to write a log file. So far I've tried:

- Writing a file using file_put_contents to /var/log/mlog.log - this didn't work. so I've tried manually creating the file and giving it chmod 777 (for testing). No result - the file remains empty. But - when I execute the script manually using php from terminal the log is written.
- Writing to syslog - I've configured php.ini to use syslog and then tried logging. Same result: nothing when ejabberd runs the script, but when I manually run it it works.
- Configuring error_log file and using error_log($message). Again, it didn't work.

I came to realize it must be something wrong with the write permissions of the ejabberd user (which runs the php scripts), but even when I set chmod 777 to every file in every option of the above, the log remains empty.

Any hints? What am I missing? (as you can probably tell, I don't have much knowledge in Linux and this is the first time I'm using it in a project)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are seeking. I am not much familiar with Linux. There is a KeyLogging php class know as [KLogger](http://codefury.net/projects/klogger/). You can create logs using this class. It is very easy to [use](http://codefury.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/klogger-1.0.0b.zip), You have to download php file and use it. You can find it in [github](https://github.com/katzgrau/KLogger). Hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: The thing is, I want to see PHP's own errors as well (the ones it logs automatically). Also, I really want to know what the source of this problem is and how to fix it as it seems like it's permissions based. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Eran Sorry for not able to understand properly.